# MacBook Pro 13" OSX 10.12.6 won't control Minecraft access with Parental Control

Tags: mac-pro, games, parental-controls

I don't want my son to use Minecraft until after he has finished his homework.
Even after applying Parental Controls (Minecraft DOESN'T show up in the list of "Allowed" applications), he can still run it at will !!!!

How do I block it's usage on a restricted account (on which it shouldn't normally run.... !) ?